# SQL Server : DELETE rows having more than 1 record (NULL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with part numbers and associated component part no and location.

Each `part_no` may have multiple components or not at all.

Here's an example

```
Part_No | Component_Part_No | Location
-----------------------------------------    
 12345  | NULL              | 001
 50001  | NULL              | 001
 50001  | 4001              | 001
 50001  | 4002              | 001
```

The part no 5001 has a NULL value as well as other components. I want to be able to DELETE  the row that has a NULL value for part 50001 but keep part no 12345 intact. The issue is that the NULL value for 50001 is not correct in the table and I need to remove those rows.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to delete literally one row from the table? Or do you have potentially many rows that fit a similar pattern?

Comment: The part no 50001 was just an example.. There are more than 16k part no so I am looking for a solution for all part nos -thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
DELETE from table
WHERE component_part_no IS NULL
AND part_no in
    (SELECT part_no 
    FROM table
    WHERE component_part_no IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: The part no 50001 was just an example.. There are more than 16k part no so I am looking for a solution for all part nos -thanks

Comment: So what do you want to delete?  Part numbers with null values that also have non null values?  i.e. why do you want to delete 50001 and not 12345?   See revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from table where Part_No = 50001 and Component_Part_No IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably prettier ways of writing it, but this should do what you want:

```
delete from Table
where Component_Part_No is null
and Part_No in (select Part_No from Table
                where Component_Part_No is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

to get this right... parts have components. if part doesn't have known components, its vital to store information about location of that part (as a whole), if part has known components, records without components are not correct, is that it?

```
delete parts
from    parts 
    inner join parts selff 
        on parts.Part_no = selff.Part_no 
            and selff.Component_Part_No is not null
where   parts.Component_Part_No is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE(Part_No INT,Component_Part_No INT,Location VARCHAR(3))
INSERT INTO @tab
SELECT 12345,NULL,'001' UNION ALL
SELECT 50001,NULL,'001' UNION ALL
SELECT 50001,4001,'001' UNION ALL
SELECT 50001,4001,'001' UNION ALL
SELECT 11111,NULL,'001' UNION ALL
SELECT 11111,5001,'002' UNION ALL
SELECT 22222,NULL,'003' UNION ALL
SELECT 22222,6001,'003' UNION ALL
SELECT 33333,NULL,'003'

SELECT * FROM @tab;

DELETE 
FROM @tab
Part_No IN 
(
SELECT Part_No 
FROM @tab
GROUP BY Part_No
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
AND [@tab].Component_Part_No IS NULL

SELECT * FROM @tab;
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/613c1/1